# React hook update data only after second click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a multi-step react form with the validation function below. onSubmit I am calling the validation function for setting errors state to display the errors and if no errors navigation user to next page. When user clicks on the "Next Step" button the display the errors. However, facing the following 2 issues.

1. When errors are displayed and the user enters all the valid data and clicks next step button, it takes 2 clicks to navigate to next page, console.log shows form is valid but still requires 2 clicks to navigate to next page.
2. When user go to next page and come back to previous page to edit form, enter any invalid data and click next button, use is redirected to next page without checking the errors.

**Validation function**

```
export default function AdBasicValidation (values){
    let errors = {}
  
    
    if(!values.make) errors.make = 'Make is required'
    if(!values.model) errors.model = 'Model is required'
    if(!values.year || values.year.length < 4) errors.year = 'Make Year is required'
   
    return errors
}



import React, {useContext, useState} from 'react'
import Select from "react-select";
import {vehicleMake} from "./car-make-data";
import {AdListingDD} from "../../AdListingDD";
import { UsedCarListingContext} from "../context/used-car-listing-provider";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router";
import AdBasicValidation from "../ad-validation";


export const AdUsedCarBasics = () => {
    const [usedCar, setUsedCar] = useContext(UsedCarListingContext)
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        const {value, models} = e
        setUsedCar({
            ...usedCar,
            make: value,
            model: '',
            trim: ''
        })
    }
    const changeMileageHandler = (e) => {
        const {name, value} = e.target
        setUsedCar({
            ...usedCar,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    const adBasicHandler = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        setErrors(AdBasicValidation(usedCar))
        const isFormValid = Object.values(errors).every(x => x === null || x === '');
        isFormValid && usedCar.make && navigate('/create-listing/ad-details')

    }

    // object of selected car
    const selectCar = vehicleMake.filter(car => car.value === usedCar.make)
    const models = usedCar.make &&  selectCar[0].models

    // object of selected model
    const selectModel = models && models.filter(model => model.value === usedCar.model)
    const trims = usedCar.make && usedCar.model &&  selectModel[0].trims


    return (

            <div className='ad-selector-container container-550 mg-0auto flex justify-evenly '>
                <form className='w-full' onSubmit={adBasicHandler}>
                    
                    <div className='ad-listing-input-wrapper mb-16-mobile mb-16 w-full-mobile flex items-center'>
                        {errors.make? <label className="ad-field-label-danger text-danger-4 font-semibold mr-40" htmlFor="make"> {errors.make} </label>:
                            <label className="listing-input-label mr-40" htmlFor="make">Make: </label>}
                        <Select
                            options={vehicleMake}
                            value={vehicleMake.filter(function(option) {
                                return option.value === usedCar.make;
                            })}
                            onChange={changeHandler}
                            placeholder='Select Vehicle Make'
                            name='make'
                            styles={AdListingDD}
                        />
                        <div className="error-container"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='ad-listing-input-wrapper mb-16-mobile mb-16 w-full-mobile flex items-center'>
                        {errors.model? <label className="ad-field-label-danger text-danger-4 font-semibold mr-40" htmlFor="model"> {errors.model} </label>:
                            <label className="listing-input-label mr-40" htmlFor="model">Model: </label>}
                        <Select
                            options={models}
                            value={models && models.filter(function(option) {
                                return option.value === usedCar.model;
                            })}
                            onChange={e => setUsedCar({...usedCar, model: e.value})}
                            placeholder='Select Vehicle Model'
                            name='model'
                            styles={AdListingDD}
                        />
                        <div className="error-container"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className='ad-listing-input-wrapper mb-16-mobile mb-16 w-full-mobile flex items-center'>
                        {errors.year? <label className="ad-field-label-danger text-danger-4 font-semibold mr-40" htmlFor="year"> {errors.year} </label>:
                            <label className="listing-input-label mr-40" htmlFor="year">Make Year: </label>}
                            <input type="text"
                                   name="year"
                                   id="year"
                                   pattern="[0-9]+([-,][0-9]+)?"
                                   min={1920}
                                   max={new Date().getFullYear()}
                                   maxLength={4}
                                   value={usedCar.year}
                                   onChange={changeMileageHandler}
                                   placeholder='Make Year'
                                   className='form-input'
                            />
                     
                    </div>
                    
                        <div className="car-basic-submission-container">
                            <div> </div>
                            <button type='submit' className='search-button bg-button-primary text-white font-semibold rounded-4' > Next Step</button>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>

     
    )
}
```

Comment: It will be helpful to create a jsfiddle, in order to understand the code.

Comment: I am still wondering why people handle forms in React on their own instead of using `React-Hook-Form` or `Formik`

Comment: @PRSHL I need searchable select and multi-select dropdowns. additionally, customisation is important in this case.